# meaning of "brd" in output of IP commands

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ethernet, subnets

In the following example:

```
$ ip a | grep scope.global
    inet 147.202.85.48/24 brd 147.202.85.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
```

What does the 'brd' mean?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`brd` is short for `broadcast`.

`147.202.85.255` is [the broadcast address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address) for whatever interface that line belongs to.